# Numpy fixed size data types behind the scenes

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, types

I am just now making some experiments with the Python C api. I have seen that numpy provides some C related numerical fixed size data types e.g. `np.int8` or `np.float64`, that should be the equivalents of C `int8_t` and `double`. I was wandering if there is a way to obtain a similar result (without using numpy), to turn a C fixed size datatype into something usable by Python. Since in my project I am already using cython I thought about using C extension types, but I have not found any implementation example of this technique applied over already-existing C data types.

Comment: Look at methods such as [`PyLong_FromLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) or [`PyFloat_FromDouble`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html#c.PyFloat_FromDouble). These accept a C type and return  `PyObject`. You can use that kind of idiom to accept whatever C type you'd like and create the right PyObject that you'd like to return on the Python side, see the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example)

Comment: @CoryKramer wouldn't `PyFloat_FromDouble` just convert a C double into a python `PyFloatObject`? I think the return object wouldn't have the precision of a double, but of a python float, wouldn't it?

Comment: A Python float [*has the precision of a double*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error). It's only *called* `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen that numpy provides some C related numerical fixed size data types e.g. `np.int8` or `np.float64`

Perhaps you misunderstand what you see.  `numpy.int8` *etc*. are Python extension types wrapping instances of native data types.  Some of their characteristics are reflective of that, but instances are still ordinary Python objects.

> I was wandering if there is a way to obtain a similar result (without using numpy), to turn a C fixed size datatype into something usable by Python.

Python code cannot work directly with native data types.  Neither Numpy nor Cython enables such a thing, though they may give you that impression.  You can create Python *wrappers* for native data types, as Numpy does, but that's more involved than you may suppose, and why reinvent the wheel?  You can also implement Python methods in C via the C API or via Cython, but using them involves converting between Python objects and native values.

> Since in my project I am already using cython I thought about using C extension types, but I have not found any implementation example of this technique applied over already-existing C data types.

That would be a viable way to create wrappers such as I mentioned above.  I don't see what you think is special about Cython extension types as applied to existing C data types, however.  Presumably, the extension type would have a single member with the wanted native type:

```
cdef class CDouble:
    cdef double value

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.value = d

    # other methods ...
```

Of course, it's all the "other methods" that will be the main trick.  There is no particular magic here; you'll need to write implementations for all the methods you need, including the methods for supporting Python arithmetic operators such as `+` (`__add__()` in that case).  Before you start down this road, you might want to run this to get an idea of what Numpy's wrapper types provide:

```
import numpy
print(dir(numpy.int8(0)))
```

I get 136 methods, and that's pretty much all per-wrapper. You might not need as much for your purposes, but you really ought to think carefully about how much work you're considering taking on, and whether the benefit is worth the effort.

Comment: Wow thanks... maybe defining a dtype metaclass would help with the implementation of `__add__`, `__sub__`...

Comment: also, is there a way to implement `cdef class CDouble: cdef double value...` just with python-C api (i mean without cython)?

Comment: @Giuppox, yes, you can use the C API directly to implement a `CDouble` class wrapping a single C `double`.  It is, in this case too, not different in kind from implementing any other extension type.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a little example on how to create a wrapper for a C data type using the python C api (without Cython)?

Comment: No I can't, @Giuppox, because there is no such thing as a *little* example of such a thing.  If you're interested in this, then you should be reading [the docs for creating extension types](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html).  It provides code examples, including some closely related to your specific request, but not a complete example.

Comment: On the other hand, @Giuppox, CPython itself contains multiple complete examples.  For instance, `PyFloatObject`, whose implemention you can find in the CPython source in [floatobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/442ad74fc2928b095760eb89aba93c28eab17f9b/Include/floatobject.h) and [floatobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/442ad74fc2928b095760eb89aba93c28eab17f9b/Objects/floatobject.c) (combined).